# Why nextLine() and not nextString() ?

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to Java and I just started learning this language.

There is one thing I don't get. I have to use `nextInt()` to get an Int from the user. But when I need to get a string I have to write `nextLine()`.

Why is that?

P.S: That can sound like a stupid question but I need to know :-)

Comment: I'll never understand why intros to Java start with Scanner. Possibly the most ill-used and unused class in the API.

Comment: it sounds like why don't we call it getInt() or readInt() rather calling nextXXX()??

Comment: 'line' is probably better here. if user types `foo bar<ENTER>`, the line is `"foo bar"`; but what should `nextString()` return? Just the `"foo"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, "why is the api the way it is" usually results in "because it is".  There's rarely an authoritative source for why someone decided an api should be the way it is, unless you can find the person who made the decision.  That uncertainty means that such questions usually end up being closed on Stack Overflow.  (My thought would be, "because a string can have a newline inside it".)

Comment: @RohitS, my guess is that the question is asking why there is no nextString() symmetry with the nextXXX() methods. And the answer is that it is ill-defined what such a method might return, as pointed out by Zhong Yu.

Comment: @jdv exactly..and yes a good explanation by zhong Yu indeed ..and talking about nextXXX() each of then defines some primitive types i guess and there is nothing like line in that case....so i guess answer is its the language designers choice..enjoy it..

Comment: @jdv, curious: what do you suggest might be a better way to introduce 'inputs' to a Java dev? (i.e. GUIs and action listeners are waaaay too much at this point, imho)

Comment: @ochi, honestly, I'd start with the fundamentals: classes, objects, methods, properties. Instead of burdening users with crufty UI that they _always_ get distracted by, I've seen instructors provide templates that wrap the classes in a test or run framework. I'd even suggest that the hours spent teaching Scanner could be better put to learning an IDE and a basic unit test framework.

Comment: @jdv but what do you suggest for inputs? classes, objects, they are part of every tutorial I ran into - what do you suggest for interaction with a program and providing inputs  though? (btw, scanner is not UI - more of a CLI) - I am not sure I follow your logic.

Comment: A CLI *is* an example of a "User Interface". I am suggesting that the reliance on UI often confuses novices, and often has nothing to do with what an example is supposed to teach. It is part of the ceremony of instructor-led development. If we need to teach ceremony, we should teach something other than Scanner, which in my _decades_ of experience I've seen used in production exactly never. Think about what "input" actually is, and the ways we can supply that to an object that side-steps all the CLI ceremony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this: nextLine return everything until next endline (\n) in form of String. Would you not think that you will retrieve everything if it was called nextString? In that case you would be posting question "why nextString() stops at endline"

tl;dr it's because it searches for endline (\n)

upd: on documenatation it refers to it as "skipped" part. I.e. cursor goes to next line and returns everything "skipped". Default output is String, so you have it: everything skipped as String.

Answer (score 1):

They are specific functions and are expecting specific user inputs. That is the way they were made.

I'd check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
to get information about them.

Specifically, look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()